# Java code not catching the error? (beginner)

Tags: java

This is what I have:

```
public class A1tester {
    static String dna = "GCTTTA";
    static String dna1 = "GCTAAAAAD";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        validChars(dna);
        validChars(dna1);
    }

    private static boolean validChars(String dna) {
        try {
            for (char c: dna.toCharArray()) {
                assert ((c == 'C') || (c == 'G') || (c == 'T') || (c == 'A'));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught!");
            return false;
        }

        System.out.println("DNA has only the permitted letters");
        return true;
    }

}
```

What am I missing that's preventing my validChars() method from identifying dna1 as containing other than the four permitted characters?

Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#enable-disable

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: Note that `assert` is meant for developers as a debugging tool. It should not be used as execution control. I strongly suggest that you use an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `assert` clause throws an [`AssertionError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) extending `Throwable` but not `Exception`. So your `catch (Exception e)` is skipped. However don't be tempted to catch `AssertionError` or `Throwable` instead.
2. Assertions have to be explicitly enabled with `-ea`. Don't rely on their existence, otherwise your program will behave differently depending on JVM arguments which you have no control over.
3. Finally do not use exceptions where you expect something to happen (to control program flow).

Instead try this:

```
private static boolean validChars(String dna) {
    for (char c: dna.toCharArray()) {
        if((c != 'C') && (c != 'G') && (c != 'T') && (c != 'A')) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I throw a custom exception (that I've created) if a boolean variable is false? Don't see how to do this with the regular try/catch block.

Comment: Exceptions aren't used to control flow. You use an `if` statement, and just return from that in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`assert` throws [`AssertionError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html) which is not a subclass of [`Exception`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html), but a subclass of [`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assert throws an Error, which is not an Exception!

Try this:

```
...
catch (Throwable e)
```

or to catch only the assertion failure:

```
catch (AssertionError e)
```